# Android Camera2 Optical Stablization

Tags: android, android-camera2

I am developing android app for capturing videos and i am using camera2 api.
I have troubles with optical stabilization option.

in one device with this data :

- Model: SM-G950F
- Product: dreamltexx
- Brand: samsung
- Device: dreamlte
- Version-Release: 9

  characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INFO_AVAILABLE_OPTICAL_STABILIZATION)

result is:

> [LENS_OPTICAL_STABILIZATION_MODE_ON , LENS_OPTICAL_STABILIZATION_MODE_OFF]

but in the other device with this data:

- Model: SM-G950W
- Product: dreamqltevl
- Brand: samsung
- Device: dreamqltecan
- Version-Release: 9

  characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INFO_AVAILABLE_OPTICAL_STABILIZATION)

result is:

> [LENS_OPTICAL_STABILIZATION_MODE_OFF, LENS_OPTICAL_STABILIZATION_MODE_OFF]

this is my stabilization method:

```
private fun chooseStabilizationMode(builder: CaptureRequest.Builder?) {
    val availableOpticalStabilization = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INFO_AVAILABLE_OPTICAL_STABILIZATION)
    if (availableOpticalStabilization != null) {
        for (mode in availableOpticalStabilization) {
            if (mode == CaptureRequest.LENS_OPTICAL_STABILIZATION_MODE_ON) {
                builder?.set(CaptureRequest.LENS_OPTICAL_STABILIZATION_MODE, CaptureRequest.LENS_OPTICAL_STABILIZATION_MODE_ON)
                builder?.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_VIDEO_STABILIZATION_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_VIDEO_STABILIZATION_MODE_OFF)
                showToast("Using optical stabilization.")
                return
            }
        }
    }

    // If no optical mode is available, try software.
    val availableVideoStabilization = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_AVAILABLE_VIDEO_STABILIZATION_MODES)
    for (mode in availableVideoStabilization) {
        if (mode == CaptureRequest.CONTROL_VIDEO_STABILIZATION_MODE_ON) {
            builder?.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_VIDEO_STABILIZATION_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_VIDEO_STABILIZATION_MODE_ON)
            builder?.set(CaptureRequest.LENS_OPTICAL_STABILIZATION_MODE, CaptureRequest.LENS_OPTICAL_STABILIZATION_MODE_OFF)
            showToast("Using video stabilization.")
            return
        }
    }

    showToast("Stabilization not available.")
}
```

**in the one S8 say “Using optical stabilization.” and the other S8 say "Stabilization not available."**

anyone can help me to understand it?

Thanks in advance.